# How would I create a sub class from this abstract class ? Vtable Error

Tags: c++, oop

I am just a beginner trying to learn C++. I am trying to solve the following problem. I have no idea what is causing the issue.

This is the abstract class I am provided with :

```
#ifndef __EXPR_H__
#define __EXPR_H__
#include <string>

class Expr {
 public:
  virtual int eval() const = 0;
  virtual std::string prettyPrint() const = 0;
  virtual ~Expr();
};
#endif
```

I am trying to create a subclass of this class, my .h file looks like this

```
#ifndef __NUM_H__
#define __NUM_H__

#include <iostream>
#include "expr.h"

//class of lone expression
class Num:public Expr
{
private:
    int operand;
public:
    Num(int operand):operand(operand){}
    int eval() const;
    std::string prettyPrint() const;
    ~Num(){}
};
#endif
```

While my implementation of Num class looks like this "num.cc"

```
#include "num.h"
#include <sstream>

std::string Num::prettyPrint()
{
    std::stringstream convert;
    convert << operand;
    return convert.str();
}

int Num::eval()
{
    return operand;
}
```

I keep getting the following error. I have no idea what is causing it.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for Num", referenced from:
      Num::Num(int) in rpn-dc20fb.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for Expr", referenced from:
      Expr::Expr() in rpn-dc20fb.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Virtual destructor needs an implementation

```
virtual ~Expr() { }
```

The compiler tries to build the virtual table given a virtual (pure or not) destructor, and it complains because it can't find the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Besides specified by P0W the functions "eval" and "prettyPrint" need to be defined as "const" in "num.cc"

```
std::string Num::prettyPrint() const
{
    std::stringstream convert;
    convert << operand;
    return convert.str();
}

int Num::eval() const
{
    return operand;
}
```